# Eclipse console output vs command line

Tags: eclipse, powershell, shell, console, console-output

I develop a small java app, I've exported as a .jar as java -jar my.jar

I developed the app in eclipse and the Eclipse output console renders correctly using Windows PowerShell as well but if I use for example a Cygwin shell it **does not** render correctly, it looks like it does not render spaces as you can see in the image bellow

[Print Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XezFJ.png)

Does someone have an idea of what can be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Where's the code that prints out that ascii art?

Comment: It is to print a square or rectangle shape as the image shows

Comment: Please show your Java code.

Comment: `protected char[][] canvas;
static final String LINE_SEPERATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator")

public void render() {
  StringBuilder drawnCanvas = new StringBuilder();

  for (int row = 0; row < this.canvas.length; ++row) {
   for (int col = 0; col < this.canvas[row].length; col++) {
    drawnCanvas.append(this.canvas[row][col]);    
   }
   drawnCanvas.append(LINE_SEPERATOR);
  }
  System.out.println(drawnCanvas.toString());
 }`

*Sorry can't format correctly

Comment: That prints only the `canvas` of chars. The code that fills in the chars into `canvas` is missing. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63626346/edit) your question to show the Java code, instead of adding comments.